# soap request in wordpress for a fedex pickup request

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to create a pickup request for fedex for a wordpress site.  I have the api and tool working fine when I create have the code outside wordpress, but when i put the same code into wordpress i'm getting and error that says

> A Warning: Illegal string offset 'Warning: Illegal string offset 'WebAuthenticationDetail' in /home/xd/public_html/test/wp-content/themes/dev/template-pickup-confirm.php on line 33 Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/xd/public_html/test/wp-content/themes/dev/template-pickup-confirm.php on line 33

There are 4 files that are needed:
pickupform.php (form that posts to pickup-request.php)
pickup-request.php (handling soap)
fedex-common.php (handling common fedex functions in case i was using other fedex tools such as rating, shipping, refunds, or cancellations)
PickupService_v13.wsdl.  (fedex webservices library)

I embedded the 2 main php forms into templates in wordpress.

I fill out the form on (pickupform.php) one and it posts to pickup-request.php

so it's stopping at this line in my pickuprequest form:

```
$request['WebAuthenticationDetail'] = array(
    'ParentCredential' => array(
        'Key' => getProperty('parentkey'),
        'Password' => getProperty('parentpassword')
    ),
    'UserCredential' => array(
        'Key' => getProperty('key'), 
        'Password' => getProperty('password')
    )
);
```

which the getProperty()is referencing this function in the fedexcommon.php:

```
function getProperty($var){

  if($var == 'key') Return 'vB12a89Q25xwv'; 
    if($var == 'password') Return 'FFAz8EEYEEfEZufZxu4pJc'; 
    if($var == 'shipaccount') Return '510087';
    if($var == 'billaccount') Return '510087';
    if($var == 'dutyaccount') Return 'XXX'; 
    if($var == 'freightaccount') Return 'XXX';  
    if($var == 'trackaccount') Return 'XXX'; 
    if($var == 'dutiesaccount') Return 'XXX';
    if($var == 'importeraccount') Return 'XXX';
    if($var == 'brokeraccount') Return 'XXX';
    if($var == 'distributionaccount') Return 'XXX';
    if($var == 'locationid') Return 'PLBA';
    if($var == 'printlabels') Return true;
    if($var == 'printdocuments') Return true;
    if($var == 'packagecount') Return '4';
    if($var == 'validateaccount') Return 'XXX';
    if($var == 'meter') Return '118593060';
);
    }
```

So it looks like for some reason wordpress doesn't know or isn't changing the WebAuthenticationDetail to an array?

Should the code be written differently for a wordpress array?

Or is this needing to be written in a plugin instead?

adding additional code at request of below:

```
require_once('library/fedex-common.php5');

//The WSDL is not included with the sample code.
//Please include and reference in $path_to_wsdl variable.
$path_to_wsdl = "wsdl/PickupService_v13.wsdl";

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

$client = new SoapClient($path_to_wsdl, array('trace' => 1)); // Refer to http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ref.soap.php for more information
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$cdate = $_POST["txtPickupDate"]. " ". $_POST["txtPickupTime"];
$datetime = new DateTime($cdate);
$tdate = $datetime->format('c');

$request['WebAuthenticationDetail'] = array(   //LINE 33
    'ParentCredential' => array(
        'Key' => getProperty('parentkey'),
        'Password' => getProperty('parentpassword')
    ),
    'UserCredential' => array(
        'Key' => getProperty('key'), 
        'Password' => getProperty('password')
    )
);
$request['ClientDetail'] = array(
    'AccountNumber' => getProperty('shipaccount'), 
    'MeterNumber' => getProperty('meter')
);
$request['TransactionDetail'] = array('CustomerTransactionId' => '*** Create Pickup Request using PHP ***');
$request['Version'] = array(
    'ServiceId' => 'disp', 
    'Major' => 13, 
    'Intermediate' => 0, 
    'Minor' => 0
);
$request['OriginDetail'] = array(
    'PickupLocation' => array(
        'Contact' => array(
            'PersonName' => $_POST["txtFromName"],
            'CompanyName' => '',
            'PhoneNumber' => $_POST["txtFromPhone"]
        ),
        'Address' => array(
            'StreetLines' => array($_POST["txtFromAddress1"]),
            'City' => $_POST["txtFromCity"],
            'StateOrProvinceCode' => $_POST["txtFromState"],
            'PostalCode' => $_POST["txtFromZip"],
            'CountryCode' => 'US')
        ),
    'PackageLocation' => $_POST["selPickupPoint"], // valid values NONE, FRONT, REAR and SIDE
    'BuildingPartCode' => '', // valid values APARTMENT, BUILDING, DEPARTMENT, SUITE, FLOOR and ROOM
    'BuildingPartDescription' => $_POST["txtFromAddress1"],
    'ReadyTimestamp' => $tdate, // Replace with your ready date time
    'CompanyCloseTime' => $_POST["txtCloseTime"]
);
$request['PackageCount'] = $_POST["txtPackageCount"];
$request['TotalWeight'] = array(
    'Value' => $_POST["txtTPackWeight"], 
    'Units' => 'LB' // valid values LB and KG
); 
$request['CarrierCode'] = 'FDXE'; // valid values FDXE-Express, FDXG-Ground, FDXC-Cargo, FXCC-Custom Critical and FXFR-Freight
//$request['OversizePackageCount'] = '0';
$request['CourierRemarks'] = 'This is a test.  Do not pickup';
```

Comment: `Return` should be `return`. Also the warning is saying that your array is being turned into a string, which isn't possible, not the other way around

Comment: Can we see the full warning, as well as the code immediately before and after the line mentioned? Where does the $request array come from? It looks like a warning then a notice, with the new line and a chunk of information deleted so they're merged into 1 message

Comment: Thanks for your help Tom!  I've added more code above.  The "return" works fine either way, but i'll make the changes to lowercase (that part of the code came directly from fedex)

Comment: Ah so you never created `$request`, can you add `$request = array();` before that and verify that's not the problem?

Comment: this is just a php question  that has nothing to do with wordpress. The error actually points you exactly where to look and it is easy to see that `getProperty` returns void for `parentkey` which I assume generates some sort of error, oor just prevent the creation of an array. Things like `getProperty` should always fire an exception/log an error when they can not handle the value being passed

Comment: Tom, i added that line and still get the exact same error.  very strange.  @MarkKaplun,  thanks for commenting as well.  As in my question though, this IS a wordpress issue to me in that all the code works fine when it's not in a framework.  Not making any changes to the code but adding it into wordpress has caused this error.  I'm trying to figure out how to get the code working in worpdress.

Comment: Sorry, but it looks like a copy-paste problem. There are things like those that Tom already mentioned, but also things like `getProperty()` which is defined … where? Please just try to fix your error and see if you have a _WordPress specific_ problem. So far I can not even see where you load this into WP or where you use a single WP API function or method.

Comment: seriously Kaiser?  I already posted the answer several days ago.  and you placed it on hold?  That makes no sense.  getproperty() was defined in the second block of code above.  And it's it's even noted.  Also EXACTLY how i put it it wordpress was explained. I feel you may have jumped onboard here without reading.  I appreciated the help Tom gave and it lead me to my answer.  Also in my answer (below) that was posted on september 5 i outlined that it was a wordpress error and it needed to be placed in a plugin to be fixed., (also part of my original question...if that was the problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was my original assumption.  I placed all my codes into functions and then made a plugin and everything is working *almost* perfectly.  The major hurdle was that because it was being handled on 2 pages and outside functions wordpress just didn't seem to know what it/I was doing.

Thanks again @tomjnowell for attempting.  I truly appreciate it.